# "Error while interpolating {{ " using angularjs in my code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am getting error when day is sunday.monday to saturday its working when day is sunday i am getting error 
    Error: Error while interpolating: {{isOpen(dealer.Day)}}
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

```
var ds= 'Sun Dec 13 2015 14:04:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
      var now = new Date(ds);
```

if you change day and date its working fine

```
var ds= 'Sat Dec 12 2015 14:04:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
      var now = new Date(ds);
```

i have added my code below pls help me out.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myCntrl", function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.isOpen = function(dealerSchedule) {
 var ds= 'Sun Dec 13 2015 14:04:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
      var now = new Date(ds);
      //var now = new Date();
      //---if you change day and date you will not get error
      //var ds= 'Sat Dec 12 2015 14:04:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
      //var now = new Date(ds);
   
      var times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[now.getDay() - 1]].replace(/(\d\d\:\d\d)(AM|PM)/g, '1/1/1900 $1 $2').split(" - ");
      var nowTime = new Date('1/1/1900 ' + now.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: true
      }));
   console.log(nowTime);
      var response = (times == "Leave" ? "Leave" : (nowTime >= new Date(times[0]) && nowTime <= new Date(times[1]) ? "Open Now" : "Closed Now"));
      return response;
    };

 
    $scope.dealers = [{

      S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com ",
      status: "",
      Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
      Day: {
        "monday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10 AM - 12:00 PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "thursday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "friday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "saturday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM",
        "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM"
      },
    }, {

      S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
      status: "",
      Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
      Day: {
        "monday": "09:00 AM - 06:00 PM",
        "tuesday": "09:00 AM - 06:00 PM",
        "wednesday": "09:00 AM - 06:00 PM",
        "thursday": "09:00 AM - 06:00 PM",
        "friday": "09:00 AM - 06:00 PM",
        "saturday": "09:00AM - 06:00PM",
        "sunday": "Leave"
      },

    }, {

      S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com",
      status: "",
      Store_Name: "sun mobile service center ",
      Day: {
        "monday": "08:30 AM - 07:30 PM",
        "tuesday": "02:30 PM - 07:30 PM",
        "wednesday": "08:30 AM - 07:30 PM",
        "thursday": "08:30 AM - 07:30 PM",
        "friday": "08:30 AM - 07:30 PM",
        "saturday": "08:15 AM - 02:15 PM",
        "sunday": "8:15 AM - 12:15AM"
      },

    }, {

      S_Email_id: "super@gmail.com ",
      status: "",
      Store_Name: "ragu mobile service center ",
      Day: {
        "monday": "10:00 AM - 10:00 PM",
        "tuesday": "10:00 AM - 10:00 PM",
        "wednesday": "10:00 AM - 04:00 PM",
        "thursday": "10:00 AM - 10:00 PM",
        "friday": "10:00 AM - 10:00 PM",
        "saturday": "leave",
        "sunday": "leave"
      },


    }]
    //var date = new Date();

    //$scope.hhmmsstt = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');
    //console.log($scope.hhmmsstt);
  })
//]]>
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js'></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <label>Search on Label</label>
    <br>
    <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name" />
    <br>
    <br>

    <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">

      {{dealer.Store_Name}}
      <br>{{dealer.S_Email_id}}
      <br>{{dealer.Day}}
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="order" />
          <span>{{isOpen(dealer.Day)}}</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

check my code i am getting error[image]

pls don't give down vote bcoze i dono why its not working i am new to technology.help me out

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with

`now.getDay() - 1` will fail for Sunday (getday() will return 0)

You should put a check for that like similar,

```
var dayCheck = now.getDay() == 0 ? 6 : now.getDay() - 1;
var times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[dayCheck]].replace(/(\d\d\:\d\d)(AM|PM)/g, '1/1/1900 $1 $2').split(" - ");
```

Comment: @martin Updated your fiddle with a few logs - check out the browser logs to see what's going on. If you output `now.getDay() - 1` on a Sunday, because `now.getDay()` returns 0, it outputs `NaN`, which causes your error. Thumbs up for Amitd's quick fix. Another recommendation is to see if you can change your JSON's data structure so the `Days` property starts with a Sunday, instead of a Monday.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from:

```
var times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[now.getDay() - 1]].replace(/(\d\d\:\d\d)(AM|PM)/g, '1/1/1900 $1 $2').split(" - ");
```

It's a bit confusing of what you are tying to achieve on this line?

Also as a note for future if you're going to put code into your questions removed commented out code as its not needed.

Also I'd consider upgrading you're angular version.

Comment: if day is sunday means i am getting error var ds= 'Sun Dec 13 2015 14:04:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
      var now = new Date(ds);check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/79/.if day is sunday means i am getting error

Comment: if its some other day its working pls check this http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/80/ .if its sunday its not working check http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/79/

Comment: Why are you parsing a date in for now? Why not just have var now = new Date();

Comment: Ok I have noticed something... Is there any particular reason why you were doing now.getDay() - 1? Is the desired to check if it is currently open right now and based on Indian timing?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is in this statement

```
now.getDay() - 1
```

Days in `Date` object are zero based indices, so on Sunday, `getDay()` will return `0` and the above statement will evaluate to `-1` which is a not valid index in your keys array of your `Day` object. To look up the `day` properly from date's `getDay()`, I suggest you use the index returned by `getDay()` and change your `Day` object so that sunday comes first and in sync with the spec like below.

```
Day: {
        "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
        "monday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10 AM - 12:00 PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "thursday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "friday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "saturday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM"
      }
```

Also there are few inconsistencies in your JSON object for `Day`

1. Sometimes you used `leave` and sometimes its `Leave`. It should be same for all Day objects
2. For the 3rd dealer (sun mobile service center), you mentioned sunday timings as `8:15 AM - 12:15AM` while it should be `8:15    AM - 12:15 PM' (from morning 8.15 - afternoon 12.15)

Correcting all these consistencies, adding some new logic for deriving dates from your Day object, here's a working [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXmeZB?editors=101) which will display **Open Now** / **Closed Now** / **Leave** accordingly.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Did you see the logic my Pen ? Its a working solution to display status based on dealer schedule & current date & time.